# How to fix edit/update error in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly but I keep getting a routing error saying No route matches [PUT] "/products" when I click on the submit button when I try to edit/update.

My routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users

  root :to => 'products#latest'

  resources :products

  match "/popular"             => "products#popular"
  match "products/like/:id"    => "products#like"
  match "products/unlike/:id"  => "products#unlike"
  match "/tags/:tag"           => "products#latest", as: :tag
```

Controller:

```
def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    p @product.id
end

def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        flash[:notice] = "Product has been updated."
        redirect_to @product
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Product has not been updated."
        render :action => "edit"
    end
end
```

Form view:

```
        <%= form_for @product, :url => products_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> 
        Product Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <br>

        Product Link: <%= f.text_field :product_link %>
        <br>

        Blog Link: <%= f.text_field :blog_link, :class => "form-control" %>
        <br>

        Blog Name: <%= f.text_field :blog_name, :class => "form-control" %>
        <br>

        Description: <%= f.text_field :description, :class => "form-control" %>
        <br>

        <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>

         <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
         <br/> 

        <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-large btn-success" %>

        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting the form to `/products` instead of `/products/<id>`.

Change your `form_for` line to

```
<%= form_for @product, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

and Rails will generate a form with the correct URL.

If for some reason you want to keep the `:url` option, you can use `:url => @product` or `:url => product_path(@product)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put "resources :products" outside the devise_for block.
To show the available routing, type in console: bundle exec rake routes

Comment: The indenting is misleading, but it isn't in a block. I moved resources to before devise and still isn't working. The other routes are working (edit, index, show, new).

Comment: Have you tried forcing to send :method => :put in the "= form_for" directive ?

Comment: Also you don't need to send :url => products_path, puting this: "= form_for @product", you tell rails to use /products in methopd put.